# Python segmentation fault calling ctypes in Centos

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, centos, ctypes

I am trying to run the below python code in CentOS, but getting error message *segmentation fault core dumped ffi_closure_unix64_inner*

```
lib=CDLL('test')

#Pointer to namespace class
namespacePointer = ctypes.POINTER(Namespace)

lib.activity.argtypes = [namespacePointer, ctypes.c_ulonglong, ctypes.c_ulonglong, ctypes.c_uint]
lib.activity.restype = ctypes.c_int

self.ptr = namespacePointer
a=50
b=64
result = lib.activity(self.ptr, a, b, 0)
```

Tried ulimit -f unlimited, but the failure persists.

Comment: Does [this issue](https://github.com/JohannesBuchner/PyMultiNest/issues/5) help?

Comment: @MichaelRuth, still getting the same error message.

Comment: Without seeing the C prototype of `activity` in the `test` library as well as the definition of `Namespace` or `self` we can't help.  Make a [mcve].